# socially responsible domain and mail hosting

Tags: hosting

I've always disliked the godaddy user experience and their mail performance has caused hours of grief for our technical people.  Now that they've released their latest batch of sleazy commercials, upper management is on board with us switching providers.

Can someone recommend a socially responsible provider for hosted domains and email?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yeah, there are so many godawful things about GoDaddy. I use them for some DNS management and find their site and user interface almost excruciating to use. I haven't seen their commercials, but I'll take your word for it that they're offensive :)

Answer (score 1):

[Google Apps](http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/business/index.html) works, but since I have no idea about your size and requirements, I don't know if it's right for you. You basically get GMail on your own domain, web hosting, etc, etc. It's pretty nice, and it seems to work OK for me. If you are a personal user, accounts with strict limits are free.

Comment: They probably aren’t *too* big if they were using GoDaddy as their mail host. Google Apps is an excellent suggestion.

Comment: I agree, Google Apps is excellent for many purposes. I've used it on a number of projects, and while I do have some complaints about a couple of aspects, it's generally great. For site hosting, it's quite limited, though.

Answer (score 0):

**1 and 1**

I've always liked 1 and 1 (http://www.1and1.com)

I'm currently hosting over 100 domains with them and have had more than that over the years.

Domains are inexpensive and I can actually get a live person when I call customer service.  I don't think I've had to wait on hold more than about 20min-30min in peak times and most of the time my wait is less than 10min.

Their online help is decent and once you've done something once on the site its pretty straight forward.

For something like $10-$20/mo you can host A LOT of domains on a single account with them.

As for email...

They do have an email interface but their web email leaves a little to be desired.  I'd recommend using something like Postbox, Thunderbird, etc as an external mail client OR (depending on your size) use Google apps for domains.

**URLs:**

http://www.1and1.com

http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/group/index.html

http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/business/details.html

Comment: http://elliottback.com/wp/1and1-sucks/

Answer (score 0):

I have found its really a case of 'you get what you pay for'.  Somebody like [Rackspace](http://www.rackspace.com/index.php) has a good reputation, but its going to cost you.

I have also used [ReliableSite](http://reliablesite.net/v3/index.asp) for cheaper hosting.  They do cop some PR flack at times, but in my experience they have been perfectly acceptable for USD 10 / month.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [Hostgator](http://www.hostgator.com/) for about 3 years and never have a critical issue, it's an excellent service.